# Trying to understand Jaspersoft and Talend Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, talend, amazon-redshift

So i am working on a server setup with AWS EC2 and Redshift for MySQL. I am going to setup an additional server with Jaspersoft. I need to generate daily and monthly reports, but i am having a problem with understanding this process.

Now, i don't clearly understand how this data generating works between jaspersoft and talend studio?

i need to generate reports and automatically put them on client's SFTP? i also have to make sure that data was generated properly and delivered to that sftp? What is the process?

Comment: Talend is an ETL tool that is bundled with Jaspersoft (a reporting tool). It can be used to get data from a variety of sources into a format that is easier to report on directly with Jaspersoft. As for your third paragraph, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch Jaspersoft ("JasperReports Server") on AWS Marketplace and pay by the hour. Here are instructions:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-aws/launch

And this is how you connect to Redshift:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-aws/connect

Yes, Talend / Jaspersoft ETL are a separate client download.

Comment: From what I am understanding Talend and Jaspersoft ETL do the same thing?

Comment: Jaspersoft ETL is a bundled Talend Open Studio with Jaspersoft branding.